# Sonicwall TZ 205W - setup guest wireless network / alternate wireless SSID

Tags: wireless, sonicwall

I have a tz 205 wireless - n running Sonic Enhanced 5.8.1.9-38o

I am trying to set it up so that it broadcasts an additional SSID that I can use for guests.

I've followed step by step the instructions listed in the [Sonicwall KB5798 article](http://www.sonicwall.com/us/en/support/2213.html?fuzeurl=http://www.fuzeqna.com/sonicwallkb/ext/kbdetail.aspx?kbid=5798)

When completed I was expecting it to broadcast the SSID Intern and I've tested and cannot any devices to recognize the new SSID.

Also, When I look at the Wireless > Status, Wireless Guest Services is listed as disabled.

I am not sure where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am still not sure why it did't work, but after messing up my primary WLAN, I reset my sonicwall back to factory, went through the wizard and "added another wireless network" after my primary and I've accomplished my goal.

I now have my primary WLAN for employees and an alternate SSID to give to guests that we can change as needed.

Comment: Thank you for following up with the solution.  Please don't forget to accept the answer after the two-day wait time expires.